# Conditionally hiding available payment gateways

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

In WooCommerce, I have a **specific product** that cannot be paid for online for legal reasons, though it can be ordered via COD.

I have written a custom hooked function to hide the payment form (Inspire Commerce credit card payments) when that **specific product** is in the cart.

When I echo out `$available_gateways` I see two options in the array, 'cod' and 'inspire' - but when I hide `Inspire` with my code, the both gateways go away and I get this error message:

> Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods  for your
>   state. Please contact us if you require assistance  or wish to make
>   alternate arrangements.

Any thoughts on why I can't just have COD?

Here is my function code:

```
function dfg_hide_payment_form($available_gateways) {
    if ($_customer['dfg-pay-later-enabled'] == 1) {
        if( is_checkout() ) {  
            global $woocommerce, $_customer;
            $packages = $_customer['dfg-package-ids'];

            foreach ($packages as $package) {
                if (gs_woo_in_cart($package)) {
                    unset($available_gateways['inspire']);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        unset($available_gateways['cod']);
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'dfg_hide_payment_form', 1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Main problem, **always return the main function argument** (`$available_gateways`) at the end when using a filter hook.

Also when using `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` hook don't forget to target only frontend, to avoid admin problems in Woocommerce settings.

I have used in this answer a cart interaction way, to check if your specific product is in cart. If the product is in cart, I unset 'inspire' payment gateway ***(Replaced a wrong variable name)***.

Here is this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_hiding_payment_gateway', 1, 1);
function conditional_hiding_payment_gateway($available_gateways) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    global $_customer;

    if ($_customer['dfg-pay-later-enabled'] == 1) {
        // HERE set your specific product ID
        $specific_product = 295;

        $is_in_cart = false;

        // Iterating through each items in cart
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
            if($cart_item['product_id'] == $specific_product){
                $is_in_cart = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($is_in_cart)
            unset($available_gateways['inspire']);
    } else {
        unset($available_gateways['cod']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is untested, but it should work…

Comment: That is basically the same as my code, which is in functions.php and after it runs I get the error message above. Did you read it?

Comment: My code works fine except the unset() call unsets everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a return statement at the end of my function.

```
return $available_gateways;
```

Comment: Oh, yes, `add_filter` always expect a return.